# How can i fine-tune qt5 for an embedded system?

Tags: qt, qt5, yocto

I am using yocto, and already have a build of qt5 in my image and it works.  The issue is that it is HUGE.

So, I tried to use a .bbappend recipe in my layer for qt where I experimented with using 
PACKAGECONFIG_remove = " qtnetworking qtdeclarative sql-mysql qtscript...etc";
and
EXTRA_OECONF = " -no-accessibility -no-feature-MDIAREA -no-feature-DRAGANDDROP ...etc";

I even removed all the feature disablement config params in EXTRA_OECONF and just added -qconfig minimal or -qconfig medium.

====> the result is always the same: compilation failure in the qt corelib or qtwidgets.

I want to disable networking, printing, and mdi support.  How can I do that?

Much appreciated!

Comment: What error message do you encounter when buildling qt corelib and qtwidgets? And exactly what are you trying to not build? I fully understand you desire to reduce build time and space; but at the same time, keep in mind that you're only going to install the parts of Qt5 that you're actually using in your image. And at the same time, remember that all combinations of things left out of PACKAGECONFIG might not build, due to internal depencencies in Qt5.

Comment: @Anders I am only including qtbase which would build and install fine in the image.

Comment: qtbase/5.2.1-r0/qtbase-opensource-src-5.2.1/src/widgets/kernel/qwindowcontainer.cpp: In member function 'void QWindowContainerPrivate::updateUsesNativeWidgets()':
/qtbase/5.2.1-r0/qtbase-opensource-src-5.2.1/src/widgets/kernel/qwindowcontainer.cpp:88:30: error: 'QMdiSubWindow' was not declared in this scope
             if (qobject_cast<QMdiSubWindow *>(p) != 0`

Comment: Well, you'll have to check which combiation of configure options you actually can use. To me it seems that qwindowcontainer uses MDI, and thus you'll have to check if you need to disable something more (or not disable MDIAREA). I can't help you with that, as I've no idea exactly what you're building.